# Appcompat crashes on Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat

I created an app that uses the appcompat v21 library to get the material look on pre-lollipop devices. 
 This app used to work, until I upgraded my phone to Lollipop. Now it crashes when I run it.
The error message is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

However, as far as I can see, I'm using the AppCompat theme everywhere.

Activity layout:

```
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:foreground="?android:windowContentOverlay"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="480dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/primaryBackground"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:listSelector="@color/listSelectedItem" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Toolbar layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
```

Styles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="myAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
        <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/list_selector</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
        <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/primaryColor2</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@color/primaryColor2</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers,
CJ

EDIT:
Added manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

    <application
        android:name=".MusicViewerApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/myAppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SetlistConcertActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_setlist"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Edit2: Added Styles-v21

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="myAppTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
        <item name="actionBarPopupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
        <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/list_selector</item>

    </style>



    <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
        <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: have you declared it in your manifest?

Comment: Did you use value `values-v21` or not.

Comment: Post your manifest file else tell us which theme you are using in manifest file ?

Comment: I've added the manifest

Comment: Do you use a different style on values-v21?

Comment: Nope, added as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your themes both use appCompat, don't use material Theme in v21 resources, that's the cause of crash, just use appCompat theme in v21 and your crash will be gone.